# How to set up fabric-java-sdk when I am configured Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: java, sdk, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I want to use `fabric-java-sdk` to write java chaincode, but I don't know how to configure develop environment? I have configured hyperledger fabric good in docker.

Comment: can you be more specific regarding your problem? SO site isn't about "how to do it", yet "how to solve this problem".

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the two following blog posts:

Java SDK for Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 (IBM Blockchain) — Setting Up the Environment
https://bertrandszoghy.wordpress.com/2017/05/12/fabric-sdk-java/

Setting up Eclipse Neon for Enterprise Java development on the Hyperledger Fabric virtual image 
https://bertrandszoghy.wordpress.com/2017/05/19/setting-up-eclipse-neon-for-java-development-on-the-hyperledger-fabric-virtual-image/

These will describe how to compile the latest fabric-sdk-java from Github, run unit and end-to-end integration tests, install Eclipse Neon for J2EE on the Hyperledger Fabric virtual machine and step through the integration test code in the IDE.

That should get you going.